# How to apply an inner shadow effect to QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, shadow, qgraphicsitem

I would like to apply an inner shadow effect to a QGraphicsItem.

I'm looking for something like QGraphicsDropShadowEffect but for inner shadow instead of drop shadow.

Thank you.